# Compare two files, print every occurrence of a pattern in the second file

Tags: awk, compare, text-processing

The tittle might not be self explanatory, but, I'm trying to create a file after comparing two files.

File1.txt

```
GO:0016020
GO:0043065
GO:0003713
GO:0007090
```

File2.txt

```
Gene1 "GO:0016020,GO:0003713"
Gene2 "GO:0016020,GO:0003713,GO:0007090"
Gene3 "GO:0003713"
```

Output.txt

```
GO:0016020 Gene1
GO:0016020 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene1
GO:0003713 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene3
GO:0007090 Gene2
```

Basically I want to print file1 plus the first column of the lines where the first column is found.

I've tried this code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next}{print a[FNR],$1}' File1.txt File2.txt > output.txt
```

The output.txt looks like this:

```
GO:0016020 Gene1
GO:0043065 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene3
```

I'm only getting one instance reported.

Would anyone please be able to help me

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk 4.* for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ \"]+" }
NR==FNR {
    split($2,a,/,/)
    for (i=1; i in a; i++) {
        genes[a[i]][$1]
    }
    next
}
{
    if ($0 in genes) {
        for (gene in genes[$0]) {
            print $0, gene
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
GO:0016020 Gene1
GO:0016020 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene1
GO:0003713 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene3
GO:0007090 Gene2
```

Comment: thanks @EdMorton . when I tried the code I got an error: 
awk: syntax error at source line 5 source file tst.awk
 context is
         >>>  genes[a[i]][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 5 source file tst.awk
awk: illegal statement at source line 5 source file tst.awk

Comment: You are not using GNU awk 4.* as I stated is required for this answer. Get it as with any other awk you are missing a TON of useful functionality.

Answer (score 3):

alternative `awk` solution without multidimensional arrays

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} {for(r in a) if(r~$1) print $1,a[r]}' file2 file1
GO:0016020 Gene2
GO:0016020 Gene1
GO:0003713 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene1
GO:0003713 Gene3
GO:0007090 Gene2
```

Comment: Nice idea, as long as the `GO:whatever` strings are all the same length as they seem to be in the sample. +1

Comment: I don't think length is relevant but they should have a common prefix which is not repeated in the content.  "GO:" will ensure that.

Comment: Length is relevant because if `GO:001602` exists in one file then it would match `GO:001602[0-9]*` in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use Unix "join", after some manipulation. Join also needs sorted files:

```
sort file1.txt > file1.sort.txt
cat file2.txt|tr -d \"|tr , " "|awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i,$1}'|sort|join - file1.sort.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that question is about awk but I've developed a solution in php that works

```
<?php
//Read File1.txt to a varaiable
$file1 = file_get_contents("File1.txt");
//Read File2.txt to a varaiable
$file2 = file_get_contents("File2.txt");
//Creates an empty array to hold the Output
$output = array();

//matches all genes on File1.txt
preg_match_all('/GO:\d+/i', $file1, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

//Loop results of genes on File1.txt
foreach($matches[0] as $gene){
    //match gene number for this specific gene in File2
    preg_match_all("/(Gene\d+).*?$gene/i", $file2, $matches2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    //Loop matches of File2.txt
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches2[1]); $i++) {
    //add to array output
    array_push($output, $gene." ".$matches2[1][$i]);
}
}

//unique genes
$output = array_unique($output);
//output the unique genes to Output.txt
foreach($output as $sortedGene){
    file_put_contents('Output.txt',$sortedGene."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
/*
GO:0016020 Gene1
GO:0016020 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene1
GO:0003713 Gene2
GO:0003713 Gene3
GO:0007090 Gene2
*/
```